# Recommended method to monitor beacons in background for long-time periods using Altbeacon

Tags: android, service, altbeacon, background-service

I appreciate an answer, considering that now is 2017 and newer Android versions like 7 (and 8 coming) have appeared since old questions asking something similar.

I want to monitor continuously (as long as the user is logged in my app) beacons in background, even if the app is killed by user or by system (when low memory) and for a long time (i.e. when the user needs some kind of help, the apps should be less probable to fail).

So the question here is which is the recommended method to do this:

1. Using `regionBootstrap` as recommended here: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html and http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html (Starting an App in the Background). I tried this but sometimes I got the monitoring working, sometimes not.
2. Using a background service which returns `START_STICKY`. I tried this but it does not seems reliable and it seems that this prevents other apps to monitor beacons at the same time.
3. Using a background service that starts as `startForeground`. I have not tried this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `RegionBootstrap` class as described in the **Starting App in the Background** section of the sample code [here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) is the recommended way of detecting in the background even after the app is killed.

Changes will likely be required to accomplish this for Android "O" due to Google's plans to restrict long running background services.  These will be addressed in a future library version to be released before "O".

Comment: Thanks for the answer @davidgyoung, but I have an issue with this: while running in foreground I got this log:

`D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON` `D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5`

but when I change the app to background, it says after seconds later:

`V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service` `W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.`

Nothing happens after that. Ranging works normally.

Comment: Some minutes later, it logs a couple `D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON` events but still not monitoring in background.

Comment: Sorry, it took me ages to find this answer, problem solved http://stackoverflow.com/a/25984352/1303826

Comment: Testing next day, it does nothing when entering the region. Unless I open the app.

Comment: It's easiest to troubleshoot these kinds of things by connecting to a computer over USB, and looking for any debug lines from your app in logcat.  If the library is set up properly to scan for beacons, you should see at least one debug line every 5 minutes coming from your app.